# How much cost GameObject.FindGameObjects takes in Unity Update function

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in which I want to player collect coins using a magnet
here is the coins spawning code

```
// Spawn Coins In Air
void SpawnCoinsInAir ()
{
  float yPos = transform.position.y + 1f;
  float zPos = transform.position.z + 4f;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i += 1)
  {
    int line =  i == 0 ? 
    RandomsPlayerController.Instance.CurrentLineIdx 
    :
    Random.Range(0, RandomsPlayerController.Instance.Lines.Count);

    for (int j = 0 ; j < Random.Range(3,6) ; j += 1) 
    {
      zPos += j + 10f;
      var it = Instantiate(
       coinTransform,
       new Vector3(RandomsPlayerController.Instance.Lines [line].x,yPos , zPos),
        Quaternion.identity
      );

      // do random rotattion in y
      it.transform.DORotate (
        Utilities.VectorY (Vector3.zero, Random.Range(-360,360)),
        1f,
        RotateMode.FastBeyond360
      )
      .SetEase (Ease.InOutSine);

      Destroy (it, actionDuration + 1f);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I got all my coins in my game and I have to find each coin by its tag and collect them in the shortest distance.

> I'm wondering how much cost it takes to find all coins in the `Update` function OR is there any way to do the same thing by keeping performance in mind?

Here is the code

```
private void UseMagnet ()
{
  // collect coins
  foreach (var coin in  GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("coin")) continue;
}

private void Update () => UseMagnet();
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrary to the generic `Find`, which you should never use if there is any other option, the `FindGameObjectsWithTag` as the name says uses a hashed (pre-indexed) *tag* which is quite optimized and not too expensive.

Of course there is still other ways to go which are even faster.

I would use a collection so the type itself can keep track of its own instances:

```
public class Coin : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static readonly HashSet<Coin> instances = new ();

    public static IEnumerable<Coin> Instances => instances;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // will automatically register itself when coming to live
        instances.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // will automatically unregister itself when destroyed
        instances.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply iterate all coins via e.g.

```
foreach(var coin in Coin.Instances)
{
    // check if close enough for your magnet e.g.
    if(Vector3.Distance(coin.transform.position, player.transform.position) <= magnetRange)
    {
        //TODO: e.g. add points ?

        Destroy(coin.gameObject);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why one private and one public? Also what happens when every instance tries to create a new static instance? Why not just create it outside of the coin once and have coins register & de-register?

Comment: @FredrikSchön what do you mean by `every instance tries to create a new static instance` ..? It is `static readonly` and there will be exactly one for the entire type .. and one is `private` which is the actual field .. the other one is a public **property** which only returns it as `IEnumerable` (basically the implicit snapshot result of `instances.GetEnumerator()`) -> you can't simply add/remove items from it somewhere else .. you can only iterate over them

Comment: Ah, I see! Neat with the enumerator! Regarding `new ();`: well, I figured that every Instantiation of GameObject with Coin attached will run the `= new ();` code, I was simply confused as how that would interact with it being static.

Comment: @FredrikSchön since it is `static` instances do not matter here at all ;) `instances = new ();` is initialized once together with the type `Coin` itself when the assembly is loaded long before any instance of `Coin` even exists

Comment: yeah I was just curious how `static` would interract with getting `new`ed over and over. I've never had code like this so my brain can't simulate it hehe. I'm guessing it just creates a reference to the static instance then

Comment: Side-question: Can this result in errors because you're looping over a list that is potentially changed during iteration, or is this automatically fixed by unity's order of things?

Comment: @FredrikSchön it is fine for the order (tested it ;) ) .. I think it is mainly because the Destroy is actually delayed until end of frame

Comment: @derHugo i have new question please answer those

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811978/how-to-smoothly-turn-character-controller-in-x-direction

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73814437/how-to-make-multiple-beams-lines-in-unity

Answer (score 2):

For smaller games, the cost is insignificant to the player. But it tends to get exponential the larger the search-space it.

> How much cost GameObject.FindGameObjects

This is a case-by-case answer, use the [profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) to see what is causing the most lag in your game.

Though [unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) did state *`For performance reasons, it is recommended to not use this function every frame`*.

> OR is there any way to do the same thing by keeping performance in mind?

Yes, what you are looking for is called **caching**.
Create a static list and store all the coins there, like so:

```
// NOTE: Alternatively, you can turn this into a singleton
public static class GlobalCache {
    // Transform or Coin Object.
    private static HashSet<Transform> coinCache = new HashSet<Transform>();

    public static Transform FetchAnyCoin() {
        if (coinCache.Count <= 0) {
            // Create a new coin, return it;
            // NOTE: Ideally, creation of coins into this cache should be done else-where.
            // The 'cache' should only handle storing and get/set requests.
            return CreateNewCoin();
        }

        var result = coinCache.First();

        // You can remove the fetched coin from the cache if you like.
        coinCache.Remove(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `For smaller games, the cost is insignificant to the player.` .. you want to avoid it wherever you can .. you might say it is insignificant in certain cases ... still it is performance you do not want to waste ^^

Comment: @derHugo Thanks I have actually one question, `how much cost raycast takes for mob games` I head my people say you should not use raycast for mob games.

Comment: @Athena again this is use case specific ... what do you use raycast for? what alternatives do you have? Do you actually have already specific notable performance peaks? Otherwise you should probably not concentrate too much on performance already. Make it work first, improve afterwards ^^

Comment: @derHugo let's suppose I have too many traffic cars or maybe an AI enemy and I wanna get some information for them using raycast should I use raycast or collider? 
if we can make collider bigger and listen for `OnCollision()` or `OnTrigger` why we should use raycast

Comment: @Athena https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-physics-colliders-or-raycast.631159/ . **TLDR;** Try both and do a performance test with the profiler. Though if your checks are simple (ex: distance-only), then it is better to just script out a simple distance check.

Comment: Your classes are all instances of objects in `c#` .. why using physics to get you close cars if you can already have their instance references stored somewhere and simply check distances etc ... again it depends on your exact use case. Raycasts might be interesting for checking which item is physically closest to you (otherwise you might only have information about the transform.position)

Comment: @derHugo Hey please answer this question if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73789823/can-i-reduce-the-default-unity-build-size-anymore

Answer (score 0):

It is considered fairly costly and is advised against using it in the Update function.

Essentially what you wish to do is to have a list over all spawned coins, and you control the spawning. This means you could easily add the spawned object to the list when you spawn it, and - if needed - remove them when you destroy them (if you dont remove them, you need to check for null in the list).

Not perfect, but depending on what you need it might work for you (not perfect because you're looping through a list asynchronously as you're adding/removing things from it)

For simplicity's sake, let's add a static (accessible anywhere) list somewhere

```cs
public static List<GameObject> SpawnedCoins = new List<GameObject>();
```

```cs
var it = Instantiate<GameObject>(coinTransform, ...);
SpawnedCoins.Add(it);

StartCoroutine(RemoveCoin(it))


IEnumerator RemoveCoin(GameObject coin, float time) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    SpawnedCoins.Remove(coin);
    Destroy(coin);
}
```

Another class

```cs
foreach (var coin in SpawnedCoins) {
    //  Check for null first, if you Destroy them they will be null in the list
    
}
```

Alternatively, Destroy and check for null and then every few seconds clear the list of nulls before running the loop.