# How to smoothly turn character controller in X Direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Overview**

I'm making an endless runner game. In this game, I have 5 lines, I want to player smoothly switch lines something like this [Ref Link](https://github.com/Zain-ul-din/To-Do-List/blob/master/ref.gif)

[image: My Game Image]

In my case, I have everything the same but instead of a car, I have a player with `PlayerController` attached to it.
I'm changing the player line on `Button click` and also on `IPointerDownHandler & IPointerUpHandler`

**Code**

[Full Code](https://github.com/Zain-ul-din/To-Do-List/blob/master/RandomPlayerController.cs)

```
[SerializeField]  private    List<Vector3>    lines; // 5 lines in my case. Vector3 (0,0,0) and so on ...
private int flag;
Vector3 currLine;

private void ChangeLines () 
{
   // Getting Inputs
   if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) { flag = -1; }
   else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) { flag = 1; }
   else flag = 0;
   
   if (flag > 0) MoveRight ();
   else if (flag < 0) MoveLeft ();
}

//I used two approaches to moving but both are not working as indented    
// 1 _ using DoTween
// 2 _ using Vector3.Lerp ()

private void MoveRight ()
{
  // some input delay for Ipointers
  if (inputDelay > 0) return;
  
  if (currLine == lines [lines.Count - 1]) return; // can't move right anymore
  transform.DoRotate (new Vector3(0, 45, 0) , 0.2f); // rotate player toward target
  transform.DoMoveX (currLine.X, 0.3f) // 0.3f is coming from inspector
  .SetEase (Ease.Linear) // i almost tried all Ease 
  .OnComplete ( ()=> DoTween.DoRotate (new Vector3(0, 0, 0) , 0.2f));
  
  // using Lerp  
  LookAt (new Vector3 (currLine.x,Y,Z));
  transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(currLine.x, ..,..), lineChangeCurve
                .Evaluate(Time.deltaTime * lineChangeSpeed)); 
}

private void MoveLeft () 
{ 
 // same code as MoveRight
}
```

**Problem**

The code I wrote is prettier much working. the player is changing lines and also rotating towards the line but I'm unable to figure out what should i need to do to make this effect look like a reference.

> Can you tell me how can I achieve the same smoother effect as the reference for my player?

[Here is the link that I made so far](https://youtu.be/lfj3nheDQlc)

[3D Assets link](https://mega.nz/file/NRtinCDI#io7dTosc9YnWU_ggQYQpU5lyrAkf4t2y75qSWmVS3hA)

Player lines distance :

```
new Vector3 (-8, 0,0)
new Vector3 (-4, 0,0)
new Vector3 (0, 0,0)
new Vector3 (4, 0,0)
new Vector3 (8, 0,0)
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: ref : https://i.ibb.co/rwv7X4z/ezgif-com-gif-maker.gif

Comment: [Something like this?](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UKS84bL0FGteSy2mJaMLXWIXzWUEFtIY/view)

Comment: @YashVakil Hey your  results are looking good but if you see the reference it seems like they are using spring

Comment: @YashVakil I don't which thing makes the reference car controller too smooth

Comment: What do you mean by Spring? And the Reference is not available now can you update it?

Comment: see gif File https://github.com/Zain-ul-din/To-Do-List/blob/master/ref.gif

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing two different animation techniques.

You do

```
transform.DoMoveX (currLine.X, 0.3f)
.SetEase (Ease.Linear)
...
```

which starts a tween animation

and then you also do `Evaluate` on the lerp which seems to be a bit redundant.

---

Your issue with the `Lerp` and `Evaluate` is

- a) that you pass in

  ```
   Time.deltaTime * lineChangeSpeed
  ```

  which basically means

  ```
   lineChangeSpeed / frame rate (e.g. 60)
  ```

  => This is a way to small value and will most probably basically mean you don't move at all (depending on your used curve)

  You want to call this every frame and pass in a value increasing from 0 to 1 here (e.g. in a Coroutine)
- b) you call it only exactly **once**. This will not result in any movement at all .. or at least only in a single step in the first frame => which probably causes a little "hiccup"

=> get rid of the lerp line all together. At best it interferes with the tween animation and is probably the cause of it looking somewhat off

---

To the question about keeping the button pressed.

You have nothing to prevent this in

```
private void ChangeLines () 
{
   // Getting Inputs
   if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) { flag = -1; }
   else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) { flag = 1; }
   else flag = 0;
   
   if (flag > 0) MoveRight ();
   else if (flag < 0) MoveLeft ();
}
```

First of all the `flag` seems quite redundant. And then you would

- Either change to `GetKeyDown` so only the first frame where the button goes down is handled
- Or add a flag that ignores all input while an animation is already running
- Or even both (depending on your desired UX)

So e.g.

```
private bool alreadyAnimating;

private void ChangeLines () 
{
    if(alreadyAnimating) return;

    
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
    // Or as said maybe even better
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
    {
        MoveLeft();
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
    // same here
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
    {
        MoveRight();
    }
}
```

and then block and reset the flag when done with moving

```
alreadyAnimating = true;

transform.DoRotate (new Vector3(0, 45, 0) , 0.2f);
transform.DoMoveX (currLine.X, 0.3f)
    .SetEase (Ease.Linear)
    .OnComplete (()=> 
        { 
            DoTween.DoRotate (new Vector3(0, 0, 0) , 0.2f)
            .OnComplete(() => { alreadyAnimating = false; })
        });
```

Comment: `transform.DoMoveX (currLine.X, 0.3f) // 0.3f is coming from inspector
  .SetEase (Ease.Linear) // i almost tried all Ease 
  .OnComplete ( ()=> DoTween.DoRotate (new Vector3(0, 0, 0) , 0.2f));` on tween compelete i'm rotating player back but when user keep pressing button it cause werid effect how can i fix this

Comment: @derHugo can you show some demo ?

Comment: @derHugo please can you answer this question ?

Comment: @Athena see update at the bottom

Comment: @derHugo after your code https://youtu.be/ad9c-BQeDiA

Comment: @derHugo solution is not working can you update this ?

Comment: @derHugo hey where are you ?

Comment: `solution is not working` what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @derHugo as you can see in the video

Comment: @derHugo can you provide demo please

Answer (score 1):

I used Lerp() for these kind of conditions and it worked well all the time. As I saw your character correctly turns but it look like a snap turn. I couldn't spot an obvious error in your code. Play a little more with the rotation time and you will get your desired result. Sorry this must be a comment but dont have the reps.

Comment: As you can see I'm using lerp but the results are not matching with reference

Comment: The last section of your Lerp function which is lineChangeCurve.Evaluate(Time.deltaTime * lineChangeSpeed) tells the lerp function the desired time to make the rotation. If you make it 1 sec it takes 1 sec for function to make the turn. Your video clearly shows that this value is so little it makes the rotation nearly in an instant

Comment: if you are able to answer this question I'll give you `100+` repo and please also show demo

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the animation for switching lines is pretty simple. All you need is an animation of turning the main character to the side and back. Let's say the line change animation takes 1 second. Then you need that when moving to the left lane, the main character makes a turn to the left in 0.5 seconds and the next 0.5 seconds turns straight again. While the gameobject moves into the adjacent line, the main character will make a small smooth turn and the animation will look better. This is how it is done in the example you showed in the question. In your video, instead of this animation, the main character abruptly turns to a certain angle and returns to its original position abruptly back when it reaches the required line.

Comment: @lgorBelikov can you show demo?