# How to draw property drawer for base type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Problem**

I want to draw `PropertyDrawer` for all `UnityEngine.Object` that can also work on those who extended `UnityEngine.Object` like `GameObject`, `Camera`, and others.

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (UnityEngine.Object))] // I also tried UnityEngine.GameObject
public class UnityObjectDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal ();
        {
         if (GUILayout.Button ("Edit", GUIStyleUtil.ButtonRight))
         {
           Debug.Log ("Hello");
         }
        }
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal (); 
    }

}
```

---

**Question**

> How can I make this happen so it can work for all `UnityEngine.Object`?

---

**Actual Goal**

I want to have a button in the inspector next to the `UnityEngine.Object` field whenever the user clicks on this button the `inspector` should open with selected gameObject

[image: Reference]

Comment: But Transform and MeshFilter and MeshRenderer are all Unity objects - they're all Components. What is your plan for those? You'll have a custom drawer that overrides Object and you'll botch all your stock inspector windows.

Comment: @Chuck i just wanna to have a button next to UnityEngine.Object field in inspector

Comment: You're saying you want a custom drawer for Object, but then you're saying the button should open the GameObject. `I want to have a button in the inspector next to the UnityEngine.Object field whenever the user clicks on this button the inspector should open with selected gameObject` If you have a `public GameObject` then you get the image you've attached, and clicking on the text in the box (`Main Camera` in your image) will expand the hierarchy and highlight the thing for you. I'm not sure what you're trying to do that's beyond the default functionality.

Comment: If you do this for any Unity object then you'll do it for all Components, as I mention above, but you can't "open" a Transform or MeshFilter, etc. on its own. Components only exist attached to a GameObject, you access them in-editor by accessing the GameObject that holds those Components.

Comment: @Chuck can you see the image I want to achieve the same thing

Comment: You can already click the object (click on "Main Camera" in your example screenshot) to `ping` the object: that will highlight it in the hierarchy window or project window

Comment: in addition to what was said - you can click for pinging the object - you can also **double click** which will already directly select the according object and thus open it in the Inspector .. if it happens to be a prefab even enters prefab edit mode ... so what is your drawer good for exactly?

Comment: @derHugo Thanks now it's working please can you answer this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811978/how-to-smoothly-turn-character-controller-in-x-direction