# ArgumentException: Getting control 1's position in a group with only 1 controls when doing repaint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Problem:-**

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (GameObject))]  
public class GameObjectDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{

    Editor gameObjectEditor;
    GameObject _gameObject;
    
    public override void OnGUI (Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
      GUILayout.Button ("Hello");
    }
}
```

Here is the code I don't know why I'm getting this error

[image: Error]

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861454/generic-check-for-base-class ? It had the potential to be a good question and it appears you're using a suggestion that will cause you grief. We are trying to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a property drawer you can not use the auto-layout calls from `GUILayout` or `EditorGUILayout`.

You rather need to use the `GUI` or `EditorGUI` and specifically pass in the exact `Rect` of where and how big to draw according field.

so in your case e.g.

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (GameObject))]  
public class GameObjectDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI (Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        GUI.Button(position, "Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811978/how-to-smoothly-turn-character-controller-in-x-direction?noredirect=1#comment130403867_73811978